# Is this a safe way to use eval() in python?

Tags: python-3.x, security, eval

I understand that running eval on user input is very dangerous, does limiting the input like I've done in the code below eliminate all the danger?

```
q=''
safe=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')', '.']
while True:
    i= input('input = ')
    if i == 'exit':
        exit('Shutting Down.')
    elif i in safe:
        q += i
    elif i == '=':
        print(eval(q))
    else:
        print('no')
```

If this still contains vulnerabilities, is there some way to add the symbols to a string of numbers and calculate the answer? I know I can simply use float() for converting the string numbers to actual numbers but I have no idea how I could add '+' as just a + so it can be used in a calculation.

Edit: Switched the code since I accidentally uploaded the wrong code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the entire input string, you can put the safe characters in a set then compare the input to the safe set.

Try this code:

```
safe=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')', '.']

safeall = set(safe)  # all safe characters

while True:
    i= input('input = ').strip()
    if i == 'exit':
        exit('Shutting Down.')
    if safeall & set(i) == set(i):  # if input in safe characters
        print('Safe')
        print(eval(i))
    else:
        print('Not Safe')
```

Output

```
input = test123
Not safe
input = ##$$%%
Not safe
input = 12 + 67
Safe
79
input = exit
Shutting Down.
```

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. I accidentally uploaded a section of code I was testing instead of the working code I had intended to, I've updated the code to the working code.

Comment: The code I uploaded already works for my intended purpose. I just wanted to know if anyone would be able to feed any dangerous code to the eval or if this would be safe to run on a server. As for testing a full string, that won't be necessary as I intend to use this with a Tkinter GUI.